# Javascript selector to effect the multiple elements

Tags: javascript

I've already created a recipe box and it works with Javascript queryselector which increases the portion number and decreases it.

The problem with queryselector is that it only effects on the first element with the specific class. So when I duplicated this element, nothing works on the second element.

```js
// Recipe calculator plus/minus actions
const plusBtn       = document.querySelector(".portion-plus");
const minusBtn      = document.querySelector(".portion-minus");
const portionNumber = document.querySelector(".portion-number span.portion-counter");
// thenum           = "foo3bar5".match(/\d+/)[0]
const portionWord   = document.querySelector(".portion-number span.portion-word");
const contentAmount = document.querySelectorAll(".content-list li span.content-amount");
let initRecipeValue = [];

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  contentAmount.forEach(elem => {
    initRecipeValue.push(elem.innerText);
  });
});

let count = 1;

// Increasing the counter

if (plusBtn && minusBtn) {
  plusBtn.addEventListener("click", () => recipeCalculation(0, 1));
  minusBtn.addEventListener("click", () => recipeCalculation(1, -1));
}

const recipeCalculation = (limit, addSub) => {
  if (count > limit) {
    count += addSub;

    //console.log(count);

    portionNumber.textContent = count;

    contentAmount.forEach((content, index) => {
      content.textContent = initRecipeValue[index] * count;
    });

    portionWord.textContent = count > 1 ? "Portionen" : "Portion";
  }
};
```

[image: javascript queryselector]

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll()` and then loop over all the elements it selects.

Comment: Your already using `querySelectorAll`? So just re-use that?

Comment: Would you please gimme a shortcode or optimization of my code?
`querySelectorAll()` returns an array, it doesn't let me select anything, right?

Comment: You need to use event delegation to clarify your code

Comment: @miladcodes, first try yourself with `querySelectorAll`. If then you still have a problem, focus your question on *that*.

Comment: I've already tried it with `querySelectorAll()`
It gets really complicated and unfortunately I'm not that professional in js

Comment: `querySelector` returns `Element`, and `querySelectorAll()` returns `[ Element, Element, Element, Element ]`. It's really not _that_ complicated (believe me... I mean if you think this is complicated, I have some bad news for you :) All you have to do is [loop over the Elements array](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/).